# Compiling Ubuntu server: "libQtGui.so: undefined reference to png functions" errors

Tags: ubuntu, qt

I want to compile wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu Server, but I have a problem with following errors:

```
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG12_0'
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_gAMA@PNG12_0'
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_PLTE@PNG12_0'
...
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG12_0'
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_bgr@PNG12_0'
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `png_get_valid@PNG12_0'
```

What can I do?

in `/usr/lib`

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1        17 2010-02-17 15:00 libQtGui.so -> libQtGui.so.4.5.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1        17 2010-02-17 14:59 libQtGui.so.4 -> libQtGui.so.4.5.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1        17 2010-02-17 14:59 libQtGui.so.4.5 -> libQtGui.so.4.5.2
-rw-r--r--  1  10071604 2009-10-14 23:34 libQtGui.so.4.5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need libpng or libpng2 installed.

`sudo yum search libpng`

and/or

`sudo yum install libpng`

Answer (score 0):

`yum` doesn't exist in Ubuntu. `yum` is in fedora or other RedHat based distributions. In Ubuntu you use `apt` so you could try :

```
sudo apt-get install libpng
```